# ASP.Net problem validating 1000's external URLs

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have a database of 1000's of external urls that I want to check every month or so. Most the urls are different hosts/domains. The problem is it seems to slow down after 100's of URLs.

Today I'm using a singleton HTTP client  in .Net Standard 2.0 library with a backport of SocketsHttpHandler. I have the same issue locally and in my Azure hosted version.

I setup sockets as follows :

```
.AllowAutoRedirect = False
.UseProxy = False
.Proxy = Nothing
.UseCookies = False
.MaxConnectionsPerServer = 50
.SslOptions = sslOptions
.ConnectTimeout = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 5) 
.PooledConnectionIdleTimeout = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 2)
```

I initiate my client as follows :

```
_Client = New HttpClient(sockets, False)
```

I use HttpRequestMessage to make the request and HttpResponseMessage to handle it. These both get disposed in a finally block.

I'm using a GET request. I did Experiment with HEAD but I found not all servers responded properly.

Adding the below to try and ensure connections get closed :

```
req.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Connection", "close")
```

I also use ResponseHeadersRead to improve performance and remove the need to read the response stream before the headers which then enables me to close the connection.

```
response = Await _Client.SendAsync(req, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead)
```

I'm wondering if it is something to do with how TCP connections work under the hood, but having read various posts I have run out of optimizations and ideas.

Comment: You should probably HEAD first and GET only for severs that don't respond?

Comment: When creating the new HttpClient, is that in a loop?

Comment: hi @CaiusJard, that's a good idea. I'd need to rework the code. I think I get a not implemented message from some servers and some just hang which is a bit more painful.

Comment: @Hursey the client is statically defined and reused.

 I think the issue isn't my code. on closer inspection it appears DNS throttling is the issue. Both my ISP and Azure have DNS throttling. Not really sure how to resolve this as I'm guessing all DNS servers have some similar limitations.

Comment: Can you check the amount of ports used when performing these requests? I usually stay away from creating a new httpclient directly, instead I use the [HttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) ensuring every client (and ports related to the httphandlers) are disposed correctly. I understand you use a static instance of the httpclient, so only one of those is used. But there might be stuff happening under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay in responding.
Thanks for your suggestions.

I have confirmed that the issue was DNS throttling on the Azure platform which was slowing the requests down. This explains why it was fast for a single domain checking links, but slow for many external links. I lost a lot of time to this and I'm not too sure how to solve it, perhaps some sort of DNS round robin.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.